# Api for gmail not working in php

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch emails from gmail in php using imap but its not working on my site. how can i do this ? Here is my code

```
<?php
    $mailbox = imap_open("{imap.googlemail.com:993/ssl}INBOX", "mygmailid@gmail.com", "mygmailpassword");
    $mail = imap_search($mailbox, "ALL");
    $mail_headers = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $mail[0]);
    $subject = $mail_headers->subject;
    $from = $mail_headers->fromaddress;
    imap_setflag_full($mailbox, $mail[0], "\\Seen \\Flagged");
    imap_close($mailbox);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a wider issue, but something similar was fixed for me. Try unlocking your account with below url. Once the account is unlocked, check if it works well.

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

[Check this discussion as well](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/FCEDjxVMCjU)

Comment: check the above discussion, you also need to enable imap on your account on gmail.